# could not run but it compiles fine Angular Project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Here is what I get when I inspect console of the browser, the project used to work fine and suddenly it stops for this error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'visit' of undefined
at convertPropertyBinding (compiler.js:7084)
at compiler.js:22230
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at createUpdateStatements (compiler.js:22226)
at compiler.js:22208
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at ViewBuilder.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.ViewBuilder._createNodeExpressions (compiler.js:22205)
at ViewBuilder.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.ViewBuilder.build (compiler.js:21677)
at compiler.js:21676
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant typescript code, you're likely accessing the `visit` property of an undefined item in a `Array.map` callback.

Comment: it's an npm problem, a problem in the compiler, all "console.log" statements become red underlined (as if npm packages are lost)
I've re installed nodejs on Windows, I've re installed the nodemodule packages of the project, nothing change

Comment: I Solved it ! I had an {{ //empty tag }}

Answer (score 0):

This is because, the value of **visit**  may be empty in certain cases.
  Just find the place where the value gets populated from. Then you could come to know about the value being undefined